# Create record in SQL Server database with HTML helper MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, create-table

I want the user to type in all data that is displayed (the columns from the database), fill them in and submit. But I cant get my code to work, what have I done wrong here? I get the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'Contact'.

Model:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Project.Contact

<h2>Create Contact</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone)</td>
    </tr>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompanyID)
</table>
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="button" name="button" class="button1" value="Create" />
}
```

Controller:

```
using Project.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Create(List<Contact> model)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO Contact";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Sublime;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                var contact = new Contact();
                                contact.Id = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Id"));
                                contact.FirstName = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("FirstName"));
                                contact.LastName = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("LastName"));
                                contact.Email = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Email"));
                                contact.Phone = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Phone"));
                                contact.CompanyID = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("CompanyID"));
                                model.Add(contact);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not also sure if my TextBoxes are properly connected to my action...

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your code. You need to hit some textbooks and learn some basic T-SQL as well as ASP.NET MVC before you have any business posting on SO.

Comment: Learn how [SQL Server Insert Statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx) works first.

Comment: What's wrong with it specific?

Comment: Your form does not even contain any form controls (they are all outside the form tags. You have not even shown you POST method (just a GET method for `Create`, and the code in that makes no sense at all).

Comment: Can I actually get any useful advice that has some code difference?

Answer (score 1):

You are using ExecuteReader, which is a method to get data, trying to perform an Insert.

You need to use ExecuteNonQuery instead; and the best practice is to add the data through parameters.

The second problem is that your INSERT command is not complete.

Then, a third problem is that you pass a list, so you need to iterate through the list, performing one INSERT per each element.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    public ActionResult Create(List<Contact> model)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Contact (Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, "
                     + "Phone, CompanyId) values (@Id,@FirstName,@LastName"
                     + ",@Email,@Phone,@CompanyID)";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Sublime;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            foreach(Contact modelElement in model)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", modelElement.Id);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", modelElement.FirstName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", modelElement.LastName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", modelElement.Email);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", modelElement.Phone);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyID", modelElement.CompanyID);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, I get "System.NullReferenceException: object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Don't use `?` as parameter placeholders for SQL Server - use *named* parameters like `@Id`, `@FirstName` etc. in your SQL query statement

Comment: Malphai, where did you get the exception? (line)